# is it possible to create pop up in edit form of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

[image]

as we can see there is link in add and remove in above image of edit pop up.Which on clicked will open list when on selecting from list will result show on dropdown.That add link can be as follows :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUl1i.jpg): http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

my first doubt is whether it is possible to do in jqgrid edit form.Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use the beforeShowForm event handler to modify the dialog at your will.